# Embeded object is always null?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have following Request body which I am trying to insert into the database:

```
{
   "vin": "1HGCR2F3XFA027534",
   "latitude": 41.803194,
   "longitude": -88.144406,
   "timestamp": "2017-05-25T17:31:25.268Z",
   "fuelVolume": 1.5,
   "speed": 85,
   "engineHp": 240,
   "checkEngineLightOn": false,
   "engineCoolantLow": true,
   "cruiseControlOn": true,
   "engineRpm": 6300,

   "tires": {
       "frontLeft": 34,
       "frontRight": 36,
       "rearLeft": 29,
       "rearRight": 34
   }
 }
```

I cannot insert it as Tires object is always mapped as null. I don't think the json object is able to map to tires object.

Here are snippets

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/readings")
public void readVehicleStatus(@RequestBody VehicleStatus vehicleStatus){
    vehicleStatusService.readVehicleStatus(vehicleStatus);
}
```

VehicleStatus.java

```
@Entity
public class VehicleStatus {

    @Id
    private String vin;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    private Double fuelVolume;
    private int speed;
    private int engineHp;
    private int engineRpm;

    private boolean checkEngineLightOn;
    private boolean engineCoolantLow;
    private boolean cruiseControlOn;

    @Embeded
    private Tires tires;

    /* getters and setters created */

}
```

Tires.java

```
   @Embeddable
   public class Tires {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       int id;

       private int frontLeft;
       private int frontRight;
       private int rearLeft;
       private int rearRight;

       /* getters and setters included */
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `VehicleStatus`  the tires json property is named `vehicleTire` but in the json is named `tires`, that's why is always null, so you should add `@JsonProperty(value="tires")`.

Here is the full code:

```
@Entity
public class VehicleStatus implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String vin;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    private Double fuelVolume;
    private int speed;
    private int engineHp;
    private int engineRpm;

    private boolean checkEngineLightOn;
    private boolean engineCoolantLow;
    private boolean cruiseControlOn;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vehicleStatus",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonProperty(value="tires") // here is the key :)
    private Tires vehicleTire;

  // Getters && Setters
}

@Entity
public class Tires implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    private Integer frontLeft; // NB try always to use wrapper type rather than primitive in jpa
    private Integer frontRight;
    private Integer rearLeft;
    private Integer rearRight;

    @OneToOne
    private VehicleStatus vehicleStatus;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

TiresRepository:

```
public interface TiresRepository extends JpaRepository<Tires, Integer>{

}
```

VehicleStatusRepository:

```
public interface VehicleStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleStatus, String>{

}
```

Example of controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleStatusRepository vehicleStatusRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/readings")
    public void readVehicleStatus(@RequestBody VehicleStatus vehicleStatus){
        vehicleStatusRepository.saveAndFlush(vehicleStatus);
    }
}
```

Main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringStackOverflowSolutionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringStackOverflowSolutionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

NB: do not forget cascadeAll, else the tires object will not be saved in the database and you will get the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : package.VehicleStatus.vehicleTire -> package.Tires
```

Comment: How would you do that with @Embeded and @Embeddable?

Comment: I think you do not need to use `@Embeded` and `@Embeddable` !

Comment: Yeah, It worked. I missed @JsonProperty on it as well, that was the key like you said, Thank you :)